# MySQL query to get data from 5 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the right MySQL query for this? Here's what I want to achieve.

1. I would like to display all status update entries, date posted, the
   poster username, gender, city, and tags
2. I would like to display all status update entries by a member with user_id='1', the date the status update was posted, the poster username, gender, city, and tags that member has on his profile
3. And how can I display all the tags that the user have on their profile, in one line separated by ','? I tried group_concat earlier but i couldn't make it work. please help.

Here's my tables

```
STATUS_UPDATE Table
+------------------------------------------------------+
| status_id | user_id |      body       |  postdate    |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1         |   1     | hello world     | Aug 12, 2012 |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| 2         |   1     | i miss you      | Aug 13, 2012 |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| 3         |   2     | lorem ipsum     | Aug 14, 2012 |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| 4         |   2     | why me? why?    | Aug 14, 2012 |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------+

MEMBERS Table    //Primary data of members
+---------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | username |  password  |   email         |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------------+
|    1    | john_doe |  qwerty    | john@doe.com    |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------------+
|    2    | maryjane |  pass123   | mary@jane.com   |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------------+

MEMBERS_DATA Table   //Profile Fields
+----------------------------------------------+
| user_id | gender |  description  |   city    |
+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+
|    1    | male   |  i am simple  | chicago   |
+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+
|    2    | female |  i am flirty  | newyork   |
+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+

MEMBERS_TAGS Table   //tags that members added to their profiles
+-------------------+
| user_id | item_id |
+---------+---------+
|  1      |  555    |
+---------+---------+
|  1      |  666    |
+---------+---------+
|  1      |  7777   |
+---------+---------+
|  2      |  8888   |
+---------+---------+


TAGS Table    //the info of the tags
+------------------------------+
| item_id | cat_id |  name     |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 555     |   5    |  sexy     |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 666     |   5    |  beauty   |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 7777    |   6    |  music    |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 8888    |   6    |  movies   |
+---------+--------+-----------+

CATEGORY Table   //the category of the tags
+-------------------------+
| cat_id  | category_name |
+---------+---------------+
| 5       |  appearance   |
+---------+---------------+
| 6       |  hobbies      |
+---------+---------------+
```

BTW I'm coding in PHP, I want to thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `SELECT b.*, a.status_id, a.body, a.postdate,
b.username, b.email, 
c.gender, c.city, c.description,
e.name
FROM status_updates a
INNER JOIN members b ON b.user_id=a.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_data c ON c.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_tags d ON d.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags e ON e.item_id=d.item_id
".($user_id ? " WHERE a.user_id=$user_id" : ""). " 
ORDER BY a.$orderby $orderdir LIMIT $limit`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      STATUS_UPDATE.* ,
      MEMBERS.username ,
      MEMBERS_DATA.gender ,
      MEMBERS_DATA.city
      TAGS.*
FROM  UPDATE
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS ON MEMBERS.user_id = STATUS_UPDATE.user_id
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS_DATA ON MEMBERS_DATA.user_id = STATUS_UPDATE.user_id
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS_TAGS ON MEMBERS_TAGS.user_id = STATUS_UPDATE.user_id
LEFT JOIN TAGS ON TAGS.item_id = MEMBERS_TAGS.item_id
```

Comment: Why not *using* in place of *on*?

Comment: both can be used but it is my practice